# Haskell-like as-patterns in Swift?

Tags: swift, haskell, pattern-matching

Does Swift have anything similar to Haskell's [as-patterns](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/As-patterns_reference.html) used in pattern matching? I'm trying to get rid of the second `switch` statement in the following piece of code by using a nested-pattern:

```swift
indirect enum Type: CustomStringConvertible {
  case Int
  case Fun(Type, Type)

  var description: String {
    switch self {
      case .Int: return "int"
      case .Fun(let p, let r):
        switch p {
          case .Fun(_): return "(\(p)) -> \(r)"
          case _: return "\(p) -> \(r)"
        }
    }
  }
}

Type.Int                             // "int"
Type.Fun(.Int, .Int)                 // "int -> int"
Type.Fun(Type.Fun(.Int, .Int), .Int) // "(int -> int) -> int"
```

The Haskell equivalent, using as-patterns, would be this:

```hs
data Type =
    Int
  | Fun Type Type

desc :: Type -> String
desc t =
  case t of
    Int -> "int"
    Fun (p @ (Fun _ _)) r -> "(" ++ desc p ++ ") -> " ++ desc r
    Fun p r -> desc p ++ " -> " ++ desc r
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the same as the Haskell as-pattern, but you can get rid of the
second switch statement with a nested pattern like this:

```
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Int: return "int"
    case .Fun(.Fun(let p, let q), let r): return "(\(Type.Fun(p, q))) -> \(r)"
    case .Fun(let p, let r): return "\(p) -> \(r)"
    }
}
```

or by rearranging the cases:

```
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Int: return "int"
    case .Fun(.Int, let r): return "int -> \(r)"
    case .Fun(let p, let r): return "(\(p)) -> \(r)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second version doesn't do what I want, which is to use parantheses to denote left-association in function types. In the end, I went with this, which uses a `where` clause: https://gist.github.com/igstan/b786d870eb28d7e73dcf5223771db6c4

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: I had already thought about that approach but considered it as "cheating" because you still use a second switch statement (just indirectly).

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed cheating, but at least the main `switch` seems easier to read. That's all.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: Btw, there was a small error in the second version. It should now give the same output as your code in the question. – Note that in your gist version the last case is never executed (unless I am mistaken). You can reduce it to 3 cases.

Comment: Yeah, works as expected now, but it gets ugly when there are other cases besides `.Int` and `.Fun`, say `.Bool` or `.String`. Now we'd have to list those nested cases as well. Thanks for your help, though. Hopefully Swift will get as-patterns in the future.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: Yes, I am aware of that. A `where case .Fun = p` clause would be a clean solution (as you wrote on the Swift mailing list).